# Fix no-await-in-loop lint warning

Tags: javascript, async-await, eslint

I need to repeat async/await block several times, but cannot use the following code:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1) {
   const res = await DoSomething();
 }
```

because it contradicts with no-await-in-loop rule.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected \`await\` inside a loop. (no-await-in-loop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957022/unexpected-await-inside-a-loop-no-await-in-loop)

Comment: Do you want to call them all at the same time or one after the other (sequentially)?

Comment: I would prefer to send them sequentially

Answer (score 18):

### Use `Promise.all` if order of iteration doesn't matter

If you don't mind code running out-of-order (meaning order of each iteration doesn't matter), just use `Promise.all` instead:

```
const promises = [];

for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1) {
  promises.push(DoSomething());
}
 
const responses = await Promise.all(promises);
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

> The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved

### Or disable the rule for that block

Otherwise if you do need to do sequential work just [disable the rule](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments) for that block:

```
/* eslint-disable no-await-in-loop */
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i += 1) {
  const res = await DoSomething();
}
/* eslint-enable no-await-in-loop */
```

#### BEWARE: `await` in a loop is, more often than not, terribly inefficient

There is a reason that the rule exists. A lot of cases where `await` is used in a loop are *wasteful* since *each iteration is not dependent on the previous one*, yet each iteration waits for the previous one to resolve before it even attempts to run the next one.

`Promise.all` is orders of magnitude more efficient in those cases since it does work in "parallel", more or less.

From [ESLint no-await-in-loop docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-await-in-loop):

> Performing an operation on each element of an iterable is a common task. However, performing an await as part of each operation is an indication that the program is not taking full advantage of the parallelization benefits of async/await.

Comment: Yeah but this question ranks higher on SEO

Answer (score 7):

ES 9 has added a new feature for asynchronous iteration.

```
for await (const line of readLines(filePath)) {
   console.log(line);
}
```

You could try it out. Hope it works.

Comment: It's worth noting that `for await...of` is only needed here if `readLines` is an asynchronous generator. A simple `for...of` works fine when something in the statement block needs to be awaited.