# for of loop and for loop with async and await sequential

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await, try-catch, for-of-loop

I have read posts such as
[Using async/await inside for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505517/using-async-await-inside-for-loop)

[Unexpected `await` inside a loop. (no-await-in-loop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957022/unexpected-await-inside-a-loop-no-await-in-loop)

I am trying to run a loop which saves some data into the db `sequentially`

somehow I am not getting it to work and it's still running in `parallel`.

I have tried both of these by using `for of loop` like such

```
for (const [index, user] of users.entries()) {
    const response = await house_user.updateOrCreate(
        { employee_id: user.employee_id },
        {
            employee_id: user.employee_id,
            phone: user.phone,
            full_name: user.full_name,
            email: user.email,
        }
    );
    await house.addToCollection(rs.id, 'users', response.id)
}
```

using `for loop`

```
for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    const response = await house_agent.updateOrCreate(
        { employee_id: users[i].employee_id },
        {
            employee_id: users[i].employee_id,
            phone: users[i].phone,
            full_name: users[i].full_name,
            email: users[i].email,
        }
    );
    await house.addToCollection(rs.id, 'users', response.id)
}
```

both ways still runs in parallel though.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and help.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/javascript-synchronization-patterns-ec8c05ac05be

Comment: Do `house_user.updateOrCreate(…)` and `house.addToCollection(…)` return promises that resolve properly? Your code should be working if they do.