# Stock value outside .map and keep it until it is reassigned js

Tags: javascript, array.prototype.map

Hello I have this function:

```
private _getServiceTask(tasks) {
    let result:;

    tasks.map(async (task, index) => {
      if (index === 0) {
        result = await callApi({
          id: task.provider_id,
        });
        return;
      }

      if (index !== 0 && task.provider_id !== tasks[index - 1].provider_id) {
        result = await callApi({
          id: task.provider_id,
        });
      }

      if (result) {
        const { providers } = result;
        providers?.map((provider) =>
          task.settings?.push({
            name_translations: provider.name_translations,
            description_translations: provider.description_translations,
          })
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

I would like to assign **result** a value and keep it until a condition is matched in .map function and result is reassigned to another value.

My issue is that in the first loop, result has value, and then is undefined. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`Array#map` does not handle waiting for `async` functions. Use a `for ... of` loop instead and make `_getServiceTask` `async`. (Also, don't use `map` to loop over an array. Use `Array#forEach` or `for` loops.)

```js
for (const [index, task] of tasks.entries()) {
  if (index === 0) {
    result = await callApi({
      id: task.provider_id,
    });
  }

  if (index !== 0 && task.provider_id !== tasks[index - 1].provider_id) {
    result = await callApi({
      id: task.provider_id,
    });
  }

  if (result) {
    const { providers } = result;
    providers?.forEach((provider) =>
      task.settings?.push({
        name_translations: provider.name_translations,
        description_translations: provider.description_translations,
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have two issues with this function. First one it says that "ESLint: Unexpected `await` inside a loop.(no-await-in-loop)". and the second one says that "Variable 'result' is used before being assigned.". It's weird

Comment: @Simon You can ignore that first warning. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957022/unexpected-await-inside-a-loop-no-await-in-loop

Comment: @Simon The second warning is probably due to TypeScript not detecting that you are checking `if (result)`.